# Java String rewriting based on a pattern

Tags: java, string

Is there a library that provides string rewriting capabilities, using regex patterns? For example I want to rewrite each "`$[a-zA-Z]+`" into "`<\img src='$old.png' />`".

The kind of API I'm looking for goes as follows:

```
SomeUtils.replaceAll(content, "$[a-zA-Z]+", new StringRewriter() {
 String rewrite(String old) { return "<img src='symbol/" + old + ".png' />"; }
});
```

I've skimmed over the Java library and Apache Commons library, but have not yet managed to find a matching functionality. Of course I could create it myself, but I'd rather use library code.

Comment: Have you tried using `String.replaceAll()`?

Comment: Although not regex-based, you might want to look into [template-engines](http://java-source.net/open-source/template-engines).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in `String.replaceAll` method will do this, but you'll need to escape some `$` signs. Something like this ought to work:

```
content.replaceAll("\\$([a-zA-Z]+)", "<img src='symbol/old$1.png' />");
```

Comment: Thanks ! Didn't know you could access the matching string by '$0'.

Comment: However, theres still a '$' in my url that I do not want.

Comment: OK, thought you still wanted it. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In the up & coming [Commons / Lang 3](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.0-beta), there will be a built-in template engine: [`StrSubstitutor`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.0-beta/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html)

**Example usage:**

```
String str =  StrSubstitutor.replaceSystemProperties(
    "You are running with java.version = ${java.version} "
    + "and os.name = ${os.name}.");
```

**Solution:**

In your case, you would have to implement a custom [`StrLookup`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.0-beta/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrLookup.html) to interpolate the variables:

```
StrLookup<String> yourCustomResolver = new StrLookup(){
    public String lookup(String key){
        return "<img src=\"" + key + ".png\" />";
    }
}
String str = new StrSubstitutor(yourCustomResolver).replace(inputString);
```